# Accessing array inside array

Tags: php

I'm working on my task right now, which accessing specific array when it is called by front end. 
My example data is like this

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Jon Snow",
            "id": "01-0001",
        },
        {
            "name": "Robert Stark",
            "id": "01-0002"
        },
        {
            "name": "Sansa Stark",
            "id": "01-002333"
        },
        {
            "name": "Arya Stark",
            "id": "01-00012"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bran Stark",
            "id": "01-0003"
        },
         {
            "name": "Rickon Stark",
            "id": "01-0005"
        }

    ]
}
```

* In my front end I have this code *

```
 selectedEmployee: any=null;

    setActiveEmployee(employee: any) {
        this.selectedEmployee = employee;
        let myJSON = JSON.stringify(this.selectedEmployee);
        this.perEmpLateEarly();
    }
```

Whenever I choose the employee i get the id of that employee.
So in this, if i choose "id": "01-0001" it will return the first array and it will keep the rest, and if I choose "id": "01-0002" it will return the second one and will keep the rest and so on. How can I do that in Php?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you "choosing the id" ? frontend or backend ? Do you mean the ID is chosen on frontend and sent to backend ?

Comment: exactly. whenever i choose the id, it will send to backend  to the get the data. @Pheonix;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will do a GET/POST HTTP request from frontend, which would look something like this in

```
your_backend_page.php?id=<ID HERE>
```

Then the "your_backend_page.php" would look like as follows:

```
$list = {  "data": [ { .... }, { ...   }] } // this is the array you have

$idFromFrontEnd = $_GET["id"];

foreach ($list["data"] as $item) {   // iterate over all items
    if ($item["id"] == $idFromFrontEnd) {   // check if id matches
       echo json_decode($item);     // if matches, print this item
    }

}
```

Please note this approach is okay if you have a small number of items. For a larger list, you might want to have a database, where you can use sql to select.